# 'ctags' command is not creating tags for C header files

Tags: c, vim, ctags

I am trying to create a tag file manually for C sources (`*.c` and `*.h`) using `ctags` command. Unfortunately the tag file is not having entries of all files, specially the header files.

I am using following command on the command prompt:

```
find . -name \*.[ch] -exec ctags {} \;
```

Kindly point out if I am missing some flag or something else above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you execute (your version):

```
find . -name \*.[ch] -exec ctags {} \;
```

then `find` executes `ctags` once for each file that is found. The `tags` file is overwritten each time, and only the tags for the last file remain.

Instead, you need to tell `find` to execute `ctags` exactly once, and specify *all* the matching files in one call. This is how you do that:

```
find . -name \*.[ch] -exec ctags {} +
```

OR (I like `trojanfoe`'s version from the comment below because it is easier to read):

```
ctags $(find . -name \*.[ch])
```

Comment: or `ctags $(find . -name \*.[ch])`.

Comment: @trojanfoe - or `find . -name \*.[ch] | ctags -L -` :-)

Comment: I think I win on *character count* ;-)

Comment: @trojanfoe - The way you wrote it is easier to read. So I included it in the answer.

Comment: I win on *usage of obscure flags* :-P